# Plot two series of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm new to Pythion and I would like to simply know how to plot the series of data resulted from the code below in a graph using the plot function?

I would like the x axis to be the results from some_function and the y axis to be the results from t1.

This is for an assignment and I can only use plot, not matplotlib as we have not been taught that.

Thanks

```py
from pylab import *

def some_function(ff, dd):
    if dd >=0 and dd <=300:
        tt = (22/-90)*ff+24
    elif dd >=300 and dd <=1000:
        st = (22/-90)*(ff)+24
        gg = (st-2)/-800
        tt = gg*dd+(gg*-1000+2)
    else:
        tt = 2.0
    return tt

t1=arange(0,12000,1000)

print(t1)

for x in t1: 
    print(some_function(55,x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want a scatter plot, or a line plot, so I've included both options.

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def some_function(ff, dd):
    if dd >=0 and dd <=300:
        tt = (22/-90)*ff+24
    elif dd >=300 and dd <=1000:
        st = (22/-90)*(ff)+24
        gg = (st-2)/-800
        tt = gg*dd+(gg*-1000+2)
    else:
        tt = 2.0
    return tt

t1=arange(0,12000,1000)

x_data = [some_function(55,x) for x in t1]
y_data = t1

# Scatter plot
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data)
# Line plot
plt.plot(x_data, y_data)

plt.show()

#Optionally, you can save the figure to a file.
plt.savefig("my_plot.png")
```

If you really can't use `matplotlib` directly, just run:

```
# Scatter plot
scatter(x_data, y_data)
# Line plot
plot(x_data, y_data)

show()

savefig('my_plot.png')
```

Comment: sorry I should have added to the original post that this is for an assignment and I can only use plot, not matplotlib as we have not been taught that.

Comment: Well, I personally think usage of `matplolib` is perfectly okay. They are almost similar. Pylab already imports matplotlib in the back. Read here http://queirozf.com/entries/matplotlib-pylab-pyplot-etc-what-s-the-different-between-these

Comment: @Sreeram TP, I understand that and it would be a lot easier however we can only use functions we have been taught and we haven't been taught plt.plot, only plot.

Comment: Regardless, just get rid of the `plt.` prefix. You're still using matplotlib behind the scenes...

Comment: @AndrewGuy I didn't tag it with matplotlib, not sure how that tag got there. Thanks for your help anyhow.